# VirtualBox Windows VM to Vagrant Base Box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have created a Windows 8 VM in VirtualBox, and have customized settings, and installed software on it.

Now I would like to turn it into a Vagrant Base Box, so that I can share with team, and also spawn many other VMs based on my cutomized windows.

It is possible to do, I have seen [Windows Base boxes in vagrantcloud](https://vagrantcloud.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=windows). Except that there is no documentation on packaging an existing windows virtualbox VM.

Please help me with instructions, or link to instructions to create a Vagrant Base Box from my existing windows VM. [creating a base box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html) documentation does not help me, as it is for linux.

Thank you in advance SO community!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can probably do that by using the `--base` argument to `vagrant package`.

First, locate the name of the VM on VirtualBox's GUI. Say it's called "Windows", you issue:

`vagrant package --base Windows --output /path/to/windows.box`

That `.box` file will be your base box. You can install it locally by using

`vagrant box install /path/to/windows.box`

Alternatively you can make it available on a server and put its URL on the `config.box_url` parameter in your `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: This is to package a VM created by vagrant. What I have is a VM not created by vagrant, I created the VM with VirtualBox manually. so `vagrant package` will error saying no vm is running now.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? It works just fine for me, I don't see why your Vagrant would be any different.

Comment: If vagrant created the VM using vagrant up, then your package command can package it, because vagrant knows about the VM. In my case vagrant does not know about the VM which I created using VirtualBox. So when I run your command I get : `:/System/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:306:in 'id=': undefined method 'children' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: That's odd. It works just fine for me. I have understood your problem right at the beginning: VM unknown to Vagrant, package into a base box. Are you running this on Windows? I'd say that this is an issue with Vagrant itself, and it's probably worth it to file a bug and/or raising it on freenode.
I have created a VM in VB (without Vagrant) and given its name to `--base` and Vagrant created my base box just fine.
Another thing to check is if you're running the latest versions of both Vagrant and VB.

Comment: You were right, I had to run this command from OUTSIDE a folder that contains Vagrantfile. I was running it from inside another git repo, which had a vagrant file in it.

Comment: Nice! I would probably still [file a bug with Vagrant](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues) as this seems like inconsistent behaviour. :)